# How to style badges of tabs in ionic 2?

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

I wish to override the default font-size, weight and style of the tabBadge in the  in ionic 2, in order to maintain the available real estate on the different form factors.

```
<ion-tabs tabsHighlight="true">  
  <ion-tab [root]="tabOne" [tabBadge]="badgeOne"  [tabTitle]="titleOne"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabTwo" [tabBadge]="badgeTwo"  [tabTitle]="titleTwo"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

[ionic 2 documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tabs/) - doesn't mention details about styling variables for `tabBadge`.

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

The badge API docs (as opposed to their component docs) can be found at https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/badge/Badge/

They indicate the follow two available sass variables for you:

> $badge-font-size  1.3rem  Font size of the badge
>
> $badge-font-weight    bold    Font weight of the badge

Further; if you go to https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/ and search for "badge" you get another dozen or so options.

Outside of that there may be more undocumented items available, or you could directly target css classes as you find them via document inspector

Comment: `$badge-font-size` & `$badge-font-weight` refer to the styling of `<ion-badge>` but not the `tabBadge` that I'm looking for in the `<ion-tab>`

Comment: Additionally I tried adding the following to the related `.scss`: `.tab-badge{ ...}` which currently solves the purpose, however I'm not sure whether it is the recommended way in ionic 2 - instead of using proper styling variables.